# How to keep the source signal's parameters while using QSignalMapper?

Tags: qt, qt4, signals-slots

I ran into a problem that I need to keep the mapped source signal's parameters. So far I only found examples to map signals without any parameter.
For example, the clicked() signal:

```
signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
signalMapper->setMapping(taxFileButton, QString("taxfile.txt"));

connect(taxFileButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
     signalMapper, SLOT (map()));

connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)),
     this, SLOT(readFile(QString)));
```

However, I would need to map some signal with its own parameters, for example the clicked(bool) signal, then the SLOT need to have two arguments doStuff(bool,QString):

```
connect(taxFileButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
     signalMapper, SLOT (map()));

connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)),
     this, SLOT(doStuff(bool,QString)));
```

However, it does not work like this? Is there any work around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QSignalMapper` does not provide functionality to pass signal parameters.

see documentation:
*This class collects a set of **parameterless** signals, and re-emits them with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal.*

There are the ways to solve that:

**If Qt4 is used** then I'd suggest to implement your own signal mapper which supports parameters what you need.
[`QSignalMapper` implementation](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/kernel/qsignalmapper.cpp) would be good example to start.

But **if Qt5 is used** then you can do exactly what you need without usage `QSignalMapper` at all. Just connect signal to lambda:

```
connect(taxFileButton, &TaxFileButton::clicked, [this](bool arg) {
    doStuff(arg, "taxfile.txt");
}  );
```

I assume `taxFileButton` is instance of `TaxFileButton` class.

If C++11 lambda is not suitable for some reason then `tr1::bind` could be used to bind `this` and `"taxfile.txt"` values.
Please note such connection will not be disconnected automatically when `this` object is destroyed.
More details are [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Comment: So there is NO easy way to do this in Qt4 other than implementing my own mapper class?

Comment: I'd be happy to get easy way as well :) . For now similar task in my project is solved in the way I described for Qt4.

Comment: Very nice. I needed it for the QLineEdit::textEdited event to map various controls into an array data structure (x and y indices). So... connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textEdited, [this](const QString &str) { OnChanged(x, y, str); });